# Expected square of frog's distance to the centre in the limit of infinite number of jumps: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}E[|r_n|^2]$

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

> Consider a unit circle on a plane and a frog in its centre. The frog
> makes infinite series of jumps. For the $n^{th}$ jump, the frog
> chooses a random point $x_n$ on the circle and jumps to the middle of the segment connecting its current position $r_n$ with the point $x_n$. Find the expected square of the frog's distance to the centre in the limit of an infinite number of jumps: $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}E[|r_n|^2]$

I'm kind of lost in this problem and don't know where to start. Albeit, I understand a few things, e.g. the area of the unit circle will be $\pi$ and the segment that will be created by $x_n$ and $r_n$, the centre of the segment would be $\frac{1}{2}$ units from the origin (unit circle). But that's it, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Just to clarify: $x_n$ is drawn at random from the circle (points at distance equal to 1) or the disk (points at distance at most 1)?

Comment: I believe $x_n$ is drawn at random from the circle (points at distance equal to 1)

Comment: Say that the frog starts at the origin, and the angle chosen at step $n$ is $\theta_n\sim U(0,2\pi)$  If $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are r.v.s giving the frog's position after $n$ steps, then $X_1= \frac12\cos\theta_1, X_2=\frac14\cos\theta_1+\frac12\cos\theta_2$, etc. and similarly for $Y_n$  I don't see an easy way to compute $E(X_n^2+Y_n^2)$ though.

Answer (score 7):

We will use complex numbers to represent points in the plane, and will assume that the center of the circle is the origin. Then

$$ r_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}(x_n + r_{n}), \qquad p_0 = 0, $$

and so,

$$ r_n = \frac{1}{2}x_{n-1} + \frac{1}{2^2} x_{n-2} + \dots + \frac{1}{2^{n-1}} x_1 = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2^k} x_{n-k}. $$

This allows to compute the expected square distance:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[|r_n|^2]
= \mathbb{E}[r_n \overline{r_n}]
= \sum_{j,k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2^{j+k}} \mathbb{E}[x_{n-j}\overline{x_{n-k}}].
\end{align*}

Since $\mathbb{E}[x_k] = 0$ and $x_1, x_2, \dots$ are independent, we have

$$ \mathbb{E}[x_{n-j}\overline{x_{n-k}}]
= \mathbb{E}[x_{n-j}]\mathbb{E}[\overline{x_{n-k}}]
= 0 \qquad \text{if } j \neq k, $$

and so,

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[|r_n|^2]
= \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{2^{2k}}
= \frac{1 - 4^{-(n-1)}}{3}.
\end{align*}

Letting $n \to \infty$ then proves that

$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{E}[|r_n|^2] = \frac{1}{3}. $$

Comment: Using complex numbers makes this so easy.  I should have thought of that!

Comment: Sorry, I didn't follow, how did you use the complex numbers and can you please describe that how did we reach the point where you defined $r_n=\frac{1}{2}(x_n + r_{n-1})$. Sorry, I'm a bit lost here. I understand the lower steps, but I didn't get the intuition at the start.

Comment: @Qhassan, I originally interpreted $r_n$ as the frog's position *after* the $n$-th jump, but it seems actually defined as the frog's position *before* the $n$-th jump. I made amend of my answer accordingly. Then the recursive formula tells that the frog's next position $r_{n+1}$ is the midpoint between the current position $r_n$ and the selected point $x_n$ on the circle. Also, I simply used complex numbers as convenient substitutes for 2-dimensional vectors, but this solution can be equally developed in terms of vectors, using the relation $\|\vec{v}\|^2=\vec{v}^{\mathsf{T}}\vec{v}$.

Comment: @SangchulLee Can you explain the immediate next step, that how is $r_n = \frac{1}{2}x_{n-1} + \frac{1}{2^2}x_{n-2} + ... \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}x_{1}$ e.g. if we want to calculate $r_n$ from the previous expression, shouldn't $r_n$ be $r_n = \frac{1}{2}(x_{n-1} + r_{n-1})$. How did you eliminate $r_n$ terms from the expression.